# r randomly assign 1 or 0 based on conditons

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, data-transform

For a dataset like this

```
    MainID    SubID     DOB            BMI
    1234      1234_A    Feb-19-2024    10.1

    1235      1235_A    Jan-11-2023    17.23
    1235      1235_B    Jan-11-2023    19.11

    5136      5136_A    May-17-2021    21.87
    5136      5136_B    May-17-2021    14.18
    5136      5136_C    May-17-2021    18.11

    3357      3357-A    Oct-06-2023    24.10   

    9124      9124-B    July-01-2021   12.09
    9124      9124-B    July-01-2021   15.06
```

I am trying to randomly assign a value 0 or 1 only if the values in MainID and DOB are same SubID is different. Expecting a dataset like this

```
    MainID    SubID     DOB             BMI   Col1
    1234      1234_A    Feb-19-2024     10.1  0

    1235      1235_A    Jan-11-2023     17.23 0
    1235      1235_B    Jan-11-2023     19.11 1

    3357      3357-A    Oct-06-2023     24.10 0

    5136      5136_A    May-17-2021     21.87 0  
    5136      5136_B    May-17-2021     14.18 0
    5136      5136_C    May-17-2021     18.11 1

    9124      9124-B    July-01-2021    12.09 0
    9124      9124-B    July-01-2021    15.06 0
```

Here only rows with ID 1235 and 5136 are assigned 0 or 1 because the repeated rows have same MainID, DOB and different SubID.

I tried options with `ifelse` and `duplicated(df[c("MainID", "DOB")])` but this did not work. Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Group by `MainID` and `DOB` and do your conditional logic by group. (The groupwise logic is not entirely clear from your description and example but it could mean just randomly assign 0 or 1 to each row within any such group with N>1, and 0 if N==1)

Comment: @Tobo, my apologies, I have updated my question, is this helpful ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if you want `0:1` sampled *with replacement*. I'm assuming always `0:1` and with-replacement only when the number of rows in a group is more than 2.

Up front, both dplyr and base-R code have a snippet similar to this.

```
sample(c(0:1, sample(0:1, size = n()-2, replace = (n() > 4))))
```

- we need to make sure that we have at least one `0` and one `1` in the bunch; if we did `sample(0:1, size=n(), replace=TRUE)`, it is feasible (though improbable) that we can have all `0`s or all `1`s, and I'm inferring that we want/need at least one of each;
- because of that we *force* at least one of each with the `c(0:1, ..)`, forcing the presence of each number;
- and since we force those two, we need the inner `sample` to produce a size of `n() - 2` (2 fewer than there are rows); if there are only four rows, then the outer `0:1` and the inner `0:1` will suffice, so we don't technically need replacement, ergo `replace=(n() > 4)`
- now that we have a vector that is guaranteed to start with `0:1` and may have zero or more `0`s and `1`s based on the number of rows in the group, we need to randomly reorder those (because we don't want the first two to be always `0:1`

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
quux |>
  mutate(
    Col1 = if (n_distinct(SubID) > 1) {
        sample(c(0:1, sample(0:1, size = n()-2, replace = (n() > 4))))
      } else 0,
    .by = c(MainID, DOB)
  )
#   MainID  SubID          DOB   BMI Col1
# 1   1234 1234_A  Feb-19-2024 10.10    0
# 2   1235 1235_A  Jan-11-2023 17.23    0
# 3   1235 1235_B  Jan-11-2023 19.11    1
# 4   5136 5136_A  May-17-2021 21.87    0
# 5   5136 5136_B  May-17-2021 14.18    1
# 6   5136 5136_C  May-17-2021 18.11    0
# 7   3357 3357-A  Oct-06-2023 24.10    0
# 8   9124 9124-B July-01-2021 12.09    0
# 9   9124 9124-B July-01-2021 15.06    0
```

## base R

```r
ave(seq_len(nrow(quux)), quux[, c("MainID", "DOB")],
    FUN = function(ind) {
      nr <- length(ind)
      nsub <- length(unique(quux$SubID[ind]))
      if (nsub > 1) sample(c(0:1, sample(0:1, size = nr-2, replace = (nr>4)))) else 0
    })
# [1] 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(MainID = c(1234L, 1235L, 1235L, 5136L, 5136L, 5136L, 3357L, 9124L, 9124L), SubID = c("1234_A", "1235_A", "1235_B", "5136_A", "5136_B", "5136_C", "3357-A", "9124-B", "9124-B"), DOB = c("Feb-19-2024", "Jan-11-2023", "Jan-11-2023", "May-17-2021", "May-17-2021", "May-17-2021", "Oct-06-2023", "July-01-2021", "July-01-2021"), BMI = c(10.1, 17.23, 19.11, 21.87, 14.18, 18.11, 24.1, 12.09, 15.06)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: There's a case of more than two SubID in the example - unless I'm hallucinating after wandering in from the pub! It seems from the tick that your conjecture is correct although the example is consistent with other patterns too.

Comment: oh yeah, right ... so my safeguard is justified ... I guess I'll put my beer down for a moment ...

Comment: @r2evans, i get different results at different iterations. If I run the script 10 times , I get the right results 2 times out of 10.

Comment: Please define "right results". For example, do you mean that you require at least one `0` and one `1` for each `MainID, DOB` group? If so, then see my edit, it is more careful about forcing some attributes outside of a purely random sample.

Comment: @r2evans, I am getting an error cannot take a sample larger than the population when `replace=false`

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of sampling. If you have 5 things to sample and take one randomly without replacement, there are 4 left, and you cannot take that same one again. You can take another, then 3 left. Once you've taken 5 things without replacement, there is nothing left to sample. If you sample with replacement, starting with 5 you take one and record what you took, then put it back, now you have 5 things available to sample again. With replacement, you can do that all day.

Comment: Try again @SundownBrownbear, the sample data didn't trigger the issue, I think I have fixed the issue (without reproducing it locally)

Comment: @r2evans, Thank you. what is the `nr>4` ? This is throwing an error.

Comment: That's a bug in the dplyr side, fixed, it should be `n() > 4`

Comment: See my edit for the intent on the seemingly complicated `sample(c(0:1, sample(..)))`